# How to do validation for unique values in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, mongotemplate

I have following documents in my mongodb:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64cc954d8e68f438ca3c44b0"),
    "empId" : "EMP-30066",
    "empName" : "Alex_Mortin",
    "dept" : {
        "name" : "CE"
    },
    "country" : {
        "name" : "US"
    },
    "qualifications" : [ ],
    "_class" : "ama.me.model.backend.Employee"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64cc954d8e68f438ca3c44a8"),
    "empId" : "EMP-30077",
    "empName" : "Luisa_Deo",
    "dept" : {
        "name" : "DG"
    },
    "country" : {
        "name" : "US"
    },
    "qualifications" : [ ],
    "_class" : "ama.me.model.backend.Employee"
},
```

I want to add a validation in my Spring Boot application before POST and PUT request to make sure in every object empId, empName, dept, country will be unique. qualifications will be ignored for validation check.

I have already got the desired result using the following query:

```
db.empLists.countDocuments({
    "empId" : "EMP-30066",
    "empName" : "Alex_Mortin",
    "dept" : {
            "name" : "CE"
        },
    "country" : {
            "name" : "US"
        }
    },{limit: 1})
```

But, I need this in **mongoTemplate** which I am using in my Spring Boot application.

Comment: You'll so much better off with unique indices rather than an extra queries.

Comment: Hey, I don't get you felly. I need this same implementation with mongoTemplate. Or, other implementation is also appreciable. @AlexBlex

Comment: [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/) guarantees no more than 1 matching document exists in the collection. In your case it will be compound index. Any application level checks are prone to race conditions, and are slower as you make additional read queries before the write query. Stackoverflow is not quite suitable to explain such fundamental concepts from the ground up, but there are free courses in mongodb uni that I would strongly recommend to everyone who started using the database.

Comment: I got your point. But, if I could set compound index, in that case can I get specific validation error for compound unique index violation. Or, it will be generic validation error from mongodb. I was wondering, how can I let the user inform about the specific validation error. @AlexBlex

Comment: But why not to try? It take less time to create an index and insert a document with a duplicate key than to ask a question. Not even saying about waiting for an answer. It will be e11000 "duplicate key" error, with details which index triggered the error in the error message. Let me stress it - although SO is a great resource, it complements education, it doesn't replace it. If you are going to work with Mongodb you need to learn it. If it is one-off task - just hire someone to do the job. You won't ask questions that you are not aware off.